# Low MongoDB insert performance with C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, bulkinsert

Here's a piece of code I've spent the last 2 days optimizing and profiling because it was taking too much time:

```
{
    mongo::ScopedDbConnection _dbConnection (DbHost);
    _dbConnection->insert(TokensDB, tokensArray );
    _dbConnection.done();
}

{
    mongo::ScopedDbConnection _dbConnection (DbHost);   
    _dbConnection->insert(IdxDB, postingsArray);
    _dbConnection.done();
}
```

Here `postingsArray` is `std::vector<BSON (int64_t, int64_t, int64_t, int)>`, 20 000 elements. This insert always takes only a couple of milliseconds. `tokensArray` is `std::vector<BSON (int64_t, std::string)>`, 5000 elements. This is the odd insert.

If I do it exactly as in the code fragment above, it takes 45-50 ms. But if I switch the two blocks around as it initially was (insert to `IdxDB` first and `TokensDB` second) it takes 400-500 ms. What is going on here? Why does order matter? Why is inserting 5000 2-field records taking much longer than inserting 20k 4-field objects?

My initial idea is it's because of `std::string` field (it holds single english word, so about 5-7 symbols on average). I've replaced it with random `int64_t` number - no noticeable change in insert completion time.

All the profiling is done on a clean database and with exactly the same data every time, I don't believe it's my error in organizing the measurements.

Comment: What about indexes? (Updating an index can take time and make the database more busy thus affecting the following insert). What about write concern (e.g. do the inserts wait for the server's acknowledge)? What happens if you do things sequentially instead of using two connections?

Comment: @ArtemGr: in the "fast" table one `int64_t` field is index. In the "slow" table `int64_t` is `_id`. I don't specify a write concern. With a single connection the behavior does not change in any visible way, that's how it initially was. The order of inserts still matters a lot.

Comment: @ArtemGr: P. S. Should I use the same connection here? Should I reuse the same connection throughout my application? Is there a recommended approach?

Comment: ScopedDbConnection is the recommended approach, NP. Try getting *two* connections. E.g. conn1(DbHost); conn2(DbHost); conn1.insert(tokensArray); conn2.insert(postingsArray); conn1.done(); conn2.done()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB performs a lot of things in the background so it is normal that the insertion of the large `postingsArray` takes little time but affects the performance after that. When you measure the `postingsArray` insert alone you are only measuring the time it takes for the MongoDB driver to accept the insert. But when you measure the consequent operations you begin to notice the background workload started by the `postingsArray` insert.
See point 6 there: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.mongodb.user/818

BTW, the way your example written I would suspect MongoDB gives you the same connection for the inserts. (E.g. you might be taking a connection from the pool, inserting the `postingsArray` with it, releasing it, then taking the same connection from the pool again and inserting the `tokensArray` with it). In that case the TCP/IP socket might still be busy with the `postingsArray` insert and what you're seeing might be hitting the limit on the TCP/IP buffer.

P.S. You might want to change the write concern in order to measure the actual time it takes for the MongoDB to perform the insert: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.mongodb.user/68288

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just realized I was measuring execution time of asynchronous calls which is meaningless and doesn't allow for detecting actual hot spots (which is what I was trying to do).